# how to tow short distance without towbar fitted

Tags: ford, towing

What is the best way to tow a light car (rx7) with a vehicle that has no towbar. I only need to move it about 15 meters up a driveway that has a bit of an incline to negotiate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you tow it from the front (uphill)? Get a tow strap, attach to the OEM anchor points on each vehicle (if available). You could push the vehicle(protecting both vehicle somehow), but damage can be done.

Option that might be preferred:

1. Buy beers
2. Invite friend over and offer some free beers
3. Put the car in neutral and ask your friends to push it.

You can also use wheel dollies (as pictured) if you need to move the car side way.

[image]

More important, be safe, block the wheel often to immobilize the vehicle and avoid to back down the slope. Have someone in the vehicle to steer/brake/handbrake in case of something might happen.

Comment: Sounds like the reasonable option!